# How to extend a SherlockFragmentActivity when implementing Facebook SDK 3.0

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to implement the Facebook SDK (3.0 beta) in an Android app that relies on ActionBarSherlock but I don't understand how since I can't extend **both** `SherlockFragmentActivity` and `FacebookActivity`.

The sample app in the Facebook SDK has:

```java
public class MainActivity extends FacebookActivity {

  private static final int SPLASH = 0;
  private static final int SELECTION = 1;
```

And the FacebookActivity looks like:

```java
public class FacebookActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish in your activity? Maybe you're approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extending `FacebookActivity` is not a requirement, but it does make your life easier when working with the Facebook integration.  See the SessionLoginSample in our sample apps to see how to integrate Facebook without using `FacebookActivity`.  You will just have to handle your own Session serialization and onActivityResult callbacks.

I would suggest extending `SherlockFragmentActivity` and then handling the Facebook integration manually.  This SO answer might also have more relevant information: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/13018745/931354

Comment: Ran into same problem. @Mike did you find any solution or followed Jess Chen's answer

Comment: I followed Chen's advice. The example code he points to is actually really easy to implement.